# Getting Error at Query: SOQL SOSL Injection while using checkmarx scan

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

```java
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> referenceRecords) { 
        try{
            List<Connection_Custom_Setting__c> connection = [select Id, CloudSync1__Instance_URL__c, CloudSync1__Access_Token__c from Connection_Custom_Setting__c where Id =: selecteddestinationOrg  OR Name =: selecteddestinationOrg limit 1];
            if(connection.size()>0){
                accesstoken = connection[0].CloudSync1__Access_Token__c;
                instanceURL = connection[0].CloudSync1__Instance_URL__c;
            }
            Map<String, String> referenceGUIDMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Object_Schema_Mapping__c objectSchemaRecord = WorkBenchUtilityController.objectSchemaMapping(referenceObjectName, selecteddestinationOrg);
            Map<String, string> recordExternalIdMap = new Map<String, String>();
            Map<Integer, string> referenceRecordMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
            string referenceRecordIds = '';
            string referenceRecordExternalIds = '';
            integer i = 0;
            for(Sobject recferenceRecord : referenceRecords){
                i = i+1;
                referenceRecordMap.put(i, (String)recferenceRecord.get('id'));
                if(objectSchemaRecord != null){
                    if(recferenceRecord.get(String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c)) != null){
                        recordExternalIdMap.put((String)recferenceRecord.get(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c), (String)recferenceRecord.get('id'));
                        if(referenceRecordExternalIds == ''){
                            referenceRecordExternalIds = '\'' + (String)recferenceRecord.get(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c) + '\'';  
                        }    
                        else{
                            referenceRecordExternalIds = '\'' + (String)recferenceRecord.get(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c) + '\'' + ',' + referenceRecordExternalIds;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        recordExternalIdMap.put((String)recferenceRecord.get('id'), (String)recferenceRecord.get('id'));
                        if(referenceRecordExternalIds == ''){
                            referenceRecordExternalIds = '\'' + (String)recferenceRecord.get('id') + '\'';  
                        }    
                        else{
                            referenceRecordExternalIds = '\'' + (String)recferenceRecord.get('id') + '\'' + ',' + referenceRecordExternalIds;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
            String referenceObjectQuery = 'Select ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(referenceObjectFields)
                + ' From ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(referenceObjectName) + ' Where '
                + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c) +
                ' IN (' + 
                referenceRecordExternalIds + ') OR ID IN (' + referenceRecordExternalIds + ')';
            CloudSync_Settings__c cloudSyncSetting = WorkBenchUtilityController.getCloudSyncSettings();
            if(cloudSyncSetting.Use_REST__c || Test.isRunningTest()){
                List<SobjectUtilityController.destinationMissingReferenceRecordsInnerClass> upsertReferenceRecordList = new List<SobjectUtilityController.destinationMissingReferenceRecordsInnerClass>();
                upsertReferenceRecordList.add(new SobjectUtilityController.destinationMissingReferenceRecordsInnerClass(referenceObjectName, database.query(referenceObjectQuery), referenceObjectFields, referenceExternalId));
                List<String> queryFields = referenceObjectFields.split(',');   
                string updateReferenceRecordsJSON = JsonUtilityController.compositeBatchUpsertJSON(selecteddestinationOrg, referenceObjectName, database.query(referenceObjectQuery), queryFields, batchProcessId);  
                httpResponse updateReferenceRecordsResponse = CallOutUtilityController.getReferenceRecordsFromDestination(accesstoken, instanceURL, updateReferenceRecordsJSON);
                JSONParser updateReferenceRecordsResponseParser;
                if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                    String updateReferenceRecordsResponseBody = '{"hasErrors":false,"results":[{"statusCode":204,"result":null}]}';
                    updateReferenceRecordsResponseParser = JSON.createParser(updateReferenceRecordsResponseBody);
                }
                else{
                    updateReferenceRecordsResponseParser = JSON.createParser(updateReferenceRecordsResponse.getBody());
                }
                String getParentRecordsJSON = JsonUtilityController.compositeBatchGetJSON(selecteddestinationOrg, referenceObjectName, database.query(referenceObjectQuery));  
                httpResponse getParentRecordsResponse = CallOutUtilityController.getReferenceRecordsFromDestination(accesstoken, instanceURL, getParentRecordsJSON);
                JSONParser getParentRecordsResponseParser;
                if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                    String getParentRecordsResponseBody = '{"hasErrors":false,"results":[{"statusCode":200,"result":'+
                                            '{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Account/0012800001NVOC3AAP"},"Id":"0012800001NVOC3AAP"}}]}';
                    getParentRecordsResponseParser = JSON.createParser(getParentRecordsResponseBody);
                }
                else{
                    getParentRecordsResponseParser = JSON.createParser(getParentRecordsResponse.getBody());  
                }
                List<CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c> cloudSyncResults = new List<CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c>();   
                string destinationRecordId = '';
                String destinationRecordObjectType = '';
                integer j = 0;
                List<CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c> listOfBacthResults =[SELECT CloudSync1__Batch_Process_Id__c,CloudSync1__Destination_Org__c,CloudSync1__Destination_Record_Id__c,
                                                                                CloudSync1__Migration_Type__c,CloudSync1__Object_Name__c,
                                                                                CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c,CloudSync1__Status__c,CreatedDate,Id FROM CloudSync1__CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c 
                                                                                where CloudSync1__Batch_Process_Id__c=:batchProcessId];
                Map<ID, CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c>  mapExistingRecords = new Map<ID, CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c> ();
                for(CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c workBenchRecord:listOfBacthResults){
                    mapExistingRecords.put(workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c,workBenchRecord );    
                }
                while (getParentRecordsResponseParser.nextToken() != null) {
                    if ((getParentRecordsResponseParser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)){
                        String fieldName = getParentRecordsResponseParser.getText();
                        getParentRecordsResponseParser.nextToken();
                        if(fieldName == 'type'){
                            destinationRecordObjectType = getParentRecordsResponseParser.getText();
                        }
                        if(fieldName == 'id') {
                            destinationRecordId = getParentRecordsResponseParser.getText();
                        }    
                        if(fieldName == 'message'){
                            j = j + 1;
                        }
                        if(destinationRecordId != '' && destinationRecordObjectType != ''){
                            j = j + 1;
                            CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c workBenchRecord = new CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c();
                            
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Status__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Status__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Status__c = 'Success';
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_Record_Id__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_Record_Id__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Destination_Record_Id__c = destinationRecordId;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_URL__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_URL__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Destination_URL__c = instanceURL;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Migration_Type__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Migration_Type__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Migration_Type__c = 'MGraph';
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Is_Parent__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Is_Parent__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Is_Parent__c = true;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Is_Lookup__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Is_Lookup__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Is_Lookup__c = true;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Fields__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Fields__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Fields__c = referenceObjectFields;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Batch_Process_Id__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Batch_Process_Id__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Batch_Process_Id__c = batchProcessId; 
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Object_Name__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Object_Name__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Object_Name__c = destinationRecordObjectType;  
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_Org__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Destination_Org__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Destination_Org__c = selecteddestinationOrg;
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Record_Source__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Record_Source__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Record_Source__c = 'LookUp';
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Result_From__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Result_From__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Result_From__c = 'Upsert';
                            }
                            if(referenceRecordMap.get(j) != null){
                                if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c.isUpdateable()
                                    && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c.isCreateable()){
                                        workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c = referenceRecordMap.get(j);
                                }
                                
                            }
                            if(Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__External_Id__c.isUpdateable()
                                && Schema.sObjectType.CloudSync_Work_Bench_Results__c.fields.CloudSync1__External_Id__c.isCreateable()){
                                    workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__External_Id__c = workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Source_Record_Id__c +  workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Result_From__c + batchProcessId + workBenchRecord.CloudSync1__Record_Source__c;
                            }
                            
                            cloudSyncResults.add(workBenchRecord);
                            destinationRecordId = '';
                            destinationRecordObjectType = ''; 
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Dumping too much code makes it harder to help you. Regardless, I suggest it is because you are not using `String.escapeSingleQuotes` when adding entries to the `referenceRecordExternalIds` string. BTW, you can simplify code that generates this sort of comma separated string using an array and `String.join`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query string:

```
String referenceObjectQuery = 'Select ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(referenceObjectFields)
        + ' From ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(referenceObjectName) + ' Where '
        + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectSchemaRecord.Source_External_Id__c) +
        ' IN (' + 
        referenceRecordExternalIds + ') OR ID IN (' + referenceRecordExternalIds + ')';
```

has a mix of escaped and non-escaped strings.

No scanner can evaluate all possible executions of the code so scanners instead look for simple, reliable logic. I've found the cleanest approach (in general) is to escape the entire string immediately before it is executed rather than escape the pieces i.e.:

```
Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(referenceObjectQuery));
```

which works fine with values such as field names, object names and values bound into the query using `:`.

So in your case:

```
Set<Id> referenceRecordExternalIds = new Set<Id>();
// Add the Ids to this set
```

then bind those sets into the query:

```
' IN :referenceRecordExternalIds OR ID IN :referenceRecordExternalIds' +
```

You will also notice that this approach simplifies the code quite a bit and so makes it easier to read.

Do remember that dynamic SOQL only supports simple binding expressions so transfer any values found through dotted expressions such as `a.b()` into a variable and bind that variable. Also the variables must be in scope when the query is executed.

Comment: On that final point about variable scope, I have found that the variable simply needs to have been declared earlier in the same method but need not actually be in scope at the point of execution; I could declare the variable in an earlier block and the later query, outside the block, can still reference it. I believe this is because Salesforce effectively creates whole-method-scope temporary variables and simply ensures these are assigned the same value as the bound variable when the bound variable is set or updated.

Comment: @PhilW That is actually a bug that one shouldn't rely on.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug, and certainly I wouldn't actually do this, but it's an interesting side-effect of the dynamic SOQL bindings implementation.

Comment: @PhilW Definitely a "not many people know that" accident/feature.

Comment: can you elaborate code accurately